React Default Browser
I want to open react apps in firefox and my default browser is chrome.
firefox is added to both git bash and cmd paths. I tried editing .env file, package.json, and set it manually in terminal. If I set the BROWSER to None it disables the browser but I can't change it to firefox for some reason.

I tried every suggested solutions yet it didn't work
